# Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined in Socket.IO application

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using Socket.IO with Node.JS:

In my single HTML page I have tried to load Socket.IO like below

```html
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.0.js"></script> 
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>
```

But sometimes while loading the application I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined` error

I have tried using referencing socket io library from the local `node_modules` folder as well as from the CDN but get the same result.

**Please note I don't get this problem every time.**

Mostly, when I make some changes in the UI code and try to refresh the page I get this error.

cheers,

Saurav

Comment: Sounds like a browser cache inconsistency issue.  Might be a problem that only occurs in development while editing files.

Comment: indeed it is....what can i do to resolve this ?...even have seen this in the production too...

Comment: If it's just in development, then just temporarily change your browser settings to clear cache upon exit and then just restart your browser between test runs.  If it occurs in production, then you will have to debug one of the actual situations where the error occurs to understand why and only then can you know what you need to change.

Comment: @saurav did you solve the issue? If yes, can you explain what is the solution? Thank you in advance